# Run dialog doesn't open the folder inside subfolder of parent directory

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-explorer, run-dialog, appdata

I like working with the keyboard a lot, so I use the run dialog often. When I try to open a subfolder from the parent directory (from run dialog) I am able to open it. For example, if I type "`appdata`" and hit Enter, AppData folder opens up.

But if I type in "`appdata\local`", it says Windows cannot find it. Why does this happen? Is there any way I can open folders inside subfolders of parent directory from run dialog using relative paths (I observed that if I type in the absolute path, it opens up the folder in Explorer)?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: No, thats how it is coded.  Run is meant to run programs, as a bonus the developer opens up teh folders as well.  You have to use the full path in the dialog.  I am confused.  Do you really go there often ?  Have you asked the wrong question ?  Is the question `how to open a particular folder quickly ?`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that that opens the actual `AppData` folder, because the KnownFolder name `Appdata` opens "...\AppData\Roaming" and `Local AppDdata` opens "...\AppData\Local". In the `Run` dialog or **Explorer** Address bar, you can access KnownFolders by prefixing their name with `shell:`, i.e.:

- `shell:AppData` opens `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming`.
- `shell:Programs` opens `%UserProifle%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
  and these do allow you to append subfolder paths:
- `shell:Local AppData\Microsoft\Feeds`.